# Flurry in Application class or each Activity

Tags: android, flurry

I'm putting Flurry Analytics in my app.
Depending on the source, it is suggested to extend the application class and initialise Flurry there.

```
public class MyApplication extends Application {
    @Override
    public void onCreate() {
        super.onCreate();

        // configure Flurry
        FlurryAgent.setLogEnabled(false);

        FlurryAgent.init(this, getResources().getString(R.string.flurrykey));
    }
}
```

or put it in each activity

```
@Override
protected void onStart()
{
    super.onStart();
    FlurryAgent.onStartSession(this, "YOUR_API_KEY");
}

@Override
protected void onStop()
{
    super.onStop();     
    FlurryAgent.onEndSession(this);
}
```

Are both correct?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

From the [latest Flurry documentation](https://developer.yahoo.com/flurry/docs/analytics/gettingstarted/android/#get-started-with-android-5-0-add-calls-to-init-onstartsession-and-onendsession), you should call `FlurryAgent.init(Context, String)` always.

However, `FlurryAgent.onStartSession(Context)` should only be called if your application is using anything less than minSdkVersion 14 (that is, if you are supporting devices below Ice Cream Sandwich).

If you are targeting minSdkVersion 14 and above, you ***do not*** need to call `FlurryAgent.onStartSession(Context)` at all. If you aren't, then you should call it in every Activity.

Answer (score 1):

You should start the session just once, then you could start it into the Main activity (if you have one activity which is alive for the whole life of the application) or into the application class.

EDIT:
The better solution is to [call onStartSession and onEndSession on each activity](http://support.flurry.com/index.php?title=Analytics/GettingStarted/Android)